# undefined method `exists' for :symbol:Symbol

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, activerecord, null

I have a table `Program` with a field calle `Symbol`.

I'd like to retrieve all Programs, that have a value in Symbol. Meaning not an empty string, and not nil.

How can I use ActiveRecord to build such a query?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :program %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.select :program_id, Program.where(:symbol.exists => true).collect {|c| [c.name + " " + c.symbol, c.id]}, {}, :class => 'chzn-select' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get this error message:

> undefined method `exists' for :symbol:Symbol

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using controller code in a view; your should move that code to your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using below syntax:

```
Program.where(:symbol.exists => true)
```

Use below syntax to search record where symbol is not nil:

```
Program.where("symbol is not null")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be something like

```
Program.where("symbol IS NOT NULL AND symbol != ''")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't call a method directly on the symbol in your finder method. Because of the syntax, it's currently calling the `#exist` method on your `:symbol` symbol of the Symbol class.

My memory for [ActiveRecord queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) is a bit bad, but you could always put a simple string condition like

```
@programs = Program.where("symbol <> ''")
```

which says symbol not null and not an empty string either.

(this goes in your controller, and then you'll be able to use the controller instance variable `@programs` in your view for your select input.)